# How to format a new line in SQL which will automatically be picked up by microsoft word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-word, newline

I am migrating data using a custom program from SQL to Microsoft Word. 
Is there a special Char(x) value or something that I should use to replace my new lines (currently stored as `"<br>"` tags) with that can be picked up by word without me having to open up each document for a find/replace?

edit:  I hadn't put `"<br>"` in a code tag, so it appeared empty and confused some commenters and myself.

Comment: Did you consider outputting the text in HTML or RTF format and read that from Word?

Comment: If you output plain text you could use the newline character. Hard to tell, what you're doing und what your _custom program_ is. Please show us the code you already have.

Comment: Are the records in a MS Word file format or are they plain text which you wish MS Word to interpret correctly?

Comment: It looks like you are storing a carriage return.  Have you tried doing nothing and see how it turns out?

Comment: Sorry, I was using br tags, but I didn't put it in a code block so it appeared empty when I published the question. The code is private and highly customized for my company, but my only question was involving SQL. I think Char(13) will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS products generally like CR+LF for line endings. ascii char 13 followed by char 10. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: So I should be able to  do a `replace([MyTextColumn],"<br>",CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))`? I'll test this out and let you know. Thanks!